# Issues clicking a button (element not interactable) in Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem clicking the **second** button because i get this error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

htlm button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-fab" type="button" 
    <span class="mdi mdi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">+</span>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-fab" type="button" 
    <span class="mdi mdi-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">-</span>
```

my code:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.amount-control > button.btn.btn-primary.btn-fab > span.mdi.mdi-plus')
button.click()
```

what my code does is locating the **second** button, the problem is I have to locate `<span class="mdi mdi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>`  to diferenciate both buttons but i think i have to click `<button class="btn btn-primary btn-fab" type="button"` not the span because it's not interactable.

How can i click the `<button>` and not the span after locating the span.

Comment: Think I gave the xpath for this in your last post.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive the parent node of an element by the following.

```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.amount-control > button.btn.btn-primary.btn-fab > span.mdi.mdi-plus')
actual_button = button.find_element_by_xpath('./..')
```

Furthermore, I would recommend you to use the following script to click an element in selenium, since selenium often has problems with clicking on elements.

```
try:
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, path)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Note that you just have to replace the `path` variable with your xpath.